# I need to import a variable from a function. How do I do it?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, data-science

I want to import a variable from one function to another, is there a way that I can implement this. 
I am trying to import the number_of_pages variable from function 2 to function 1 so that I can loop the number of pages through the url below. 
Below is the two functions :

function 1

```
def forge_url(self, year):
    print('Year:', year)
    for page in range(1, number_of_pages, 1):
        print('Page:', page)
        url = 'https://www.example.com/annonce/page?context=add_hit_meta%3Dnumeroparution%2540numeroparution%26add_hit_meta%3Ddatepublication%2540datepublication%26add_hit_meta%3Dnojo%2540nojo%26add_hit_meta%3Dnom%2540nom%26add_hit_meta%3Dprenom%2540prenom%26add_hit_meta%3Dtribunal%2540tribunal%26add_hit_meta%3Drm%2540rm%26add_hit_meta%3Drcs%2540rcs%26add_hit_meta%3Dnumeroannonce%2540numeroannonce%26add_hit_meta%3Dnumerodepartement%2540numerodepartement%26add_hit_meta%3Ddenomination%2540denomination%26add_hit_meta%3Dxmlbody%2540xmlbody%26s%3Ddatepublication%26b%3D0%26q%3D%2528proc%25C3%25A9dure%2Bcollective%2529%2B%2528%2528datepublication%253E%253D{}%2529%2B%2BAND%2B%2528datepublication%253C%253D{}%2529%2B%2529%2Bnumerodepartement%253A%252875%2529%26sa%3D1%26n%3DslBodaccDiffusion%26target%3DstBodaccDiffusion%26hf%3D10%26add_category_group%3Dpublication_cat%2540Top%252Fpublication_cat%253A1%26add_category_group%3Dcategorieannonce_cat%2540Top%252Fcategorieannonce_cat%253A1%26add_category_group%3Dtypeannonce_cat%2540Top%252Ftypeannonce_cat%253A1%26lang%3Dfr&page={}'.format(year, year+1, page)
        yield url
```

function 2

```
def get_pages(self, doc, url):
    listings_extract = doc.xpath("//*[@id='resultats']/h3/text()")
    listings = ''.join(listings_extract)
    listings = int(re.search(r'\d+', listings).group())
    number_of_pages = round(listings/10)
    return number_of_pages
```

Comment: Are these functions both methods of the same class?

Comment: Yes, they are of the same class

Comment: In that case adding `self.` in front of a variable makes it an instance attribute which in turn can be shared across class methods or functions. So simply changing this line to `self.number_of_pages = round(listings/10)` allows you to use it in this line like `for page in range(1, self.number_of_pages, 1):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't need to use a variable from function 2 - this variable can be *returned* from the function.

```py
number_of_pages = self.get_pages(doc, url)
```

So, you can write something like:

```py
def forge_url(self, year):
    number_of_pages = self.get_pages(doc, url)
    print('Year:', year)
    for page in range(number_of_pages):
        print('Page:', page)
        url = 'this very big url of yours'.format(year, year+1, page)
        yield url
```

Please note, that it is unclear from your code where `doc` and `url` parameters should be coming from, so I just added them as if they were defined.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `self.get_pages(doc, url)` ?

Comment: @Axe319 Yes, I missed that. Fixed